# Negative pinching and Ricci flow

Tags: reference-request, ricci-flow

Let $\varepsilon>0$ be sufficiently small.
Denote by $\mathrm{Rm}$ and $\mathrm{R}$ the curvature operator and the scalar curvature.

Consider the following pinching condition
$$\langle\mathrm{Rm}\,\phi,\phi\rangle\ge -\varepsilon\,\mathrm{R}\,|\phi|^2$$
for any tangent bivector $\phi$.

**Questions**

1. Is this piching preserved under Ricci flow?
   (This is true in 3-dimensional case, see [Bing-Long Chen, Guoyi Xu, Zhuhong Zhang, Local pinching estimates in 3-dim Ricci flow](https://arxiv.org/abs/1206.1814).)
2. If yes, any references?
3. If no, is there any cone of curvature operators which is preserved under Ricci flow and just little wider than the cone $\mathrm{Rm}\ge 0$.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, this question is not addressed anywhere.

However, I have to say I don't expect this precise estimate to hold. At least, it doesn't seem to follow from Hamilton's maximum principle.

The closest thing I know is the work of Miles Simon in dimension 3 (http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0612095). Lemma 4.1 looks like the kind of estimate you are looking for but with a time dependent $\varepsilon$ and an additive constant added in, for Ricci curvature in dimension 3. It is valid only for short time.

I actually tried to generalise Simon's estimate to the curvature operator in arbitrary dimensions. The closest thing I ended up with can be found here (http://arxiv.org/abs/1111.0859), this is Theorem 1.3. Unfortunately, it is really weaker than what you want.